# Phonegap: Can't get Email Composer to work

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I've spent a couple of days trying to implement emailing functionality to my app, but I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to use the plugin (or plugins, as description claims) from here: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/705

I've added the following code to my XML file:

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.1" />
```

Then for testing I created a simple page with a simple code, just to see how it would look. Here is how my JS piece looks:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
 $('#composertest').click(function(){
 alert('tapped');
 window.plugin.email.isServiceAvailable(function (isAvailable) {
        if (!isAvailable){
         alert('Service is not available');
        }else {
         alert('Service is available');
        }
    });
 window.plugin.email.open();
 alert('worked(?)');
 });
}, false);
```

The weird thing is that I get both alerts "tapped" and "worked", so if there would be an error, the last alert shouldn't be executed. However I don't get any popup or new window, the plugin seems to do nothing. Alerts about the service don't fire. I've tried to return the type of window.plugin.email in alert and it wrote "Object", so it is not undefined.

I've tried so many things now (including other plugins) that I'm completely lost with clues. Last time I tried to remove JQMobile, but it didn't change anything. Right now the code is very simple and uses as few files as possible and still it doesn't work. I've also tried to make a lot of changes in the code (and also tried the exact example from the docs page) and never got to the point where plugin does anything.

Am I missing something? Is there a working example somewhere?

PS: Phonegap debugger doesn't return any errors, although I don't trust it too much, since it's quite buggy.

Comment: Try checking if window.plugin.email.isServiceAvailable is defined.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you just want to open email with repopulated info? If so there is a much simpler way.

Comment: I don't think that checking window.plugin.email.isServiceAvailable would give anything (I also think I already tried it too), since it doesn't work without this part of code (when I just call to open email).

Yeah, I want to open an email with prepopulated fields. I want then to style it if possible, but for now even prepopulated standard design would work. The thing is this plugin doesn't work neither with prepopulated fields nor without them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send a mail within PhoneGap you can just use mailto URI scheme.

Here are some links:

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto

This will send an email intent in Android then the user can choose which app to open the mail in.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the advice. But would it work with HTML contents of the body? In my emails I need lots of styling, including pictures etc.

Comment: Its not suited for heavy styling, though you can include images.

Comment: Yeah, then it's not what I need. I'm thinking of own email server for this, but it would be better if emails would come from user's address.